# Learning Python regex, why can’t I use AND operator in if statement?

Tags: python

I’m trying to create a very basic mock password verification program to get more comfortable with meta characters. The program is supposed to take an input, use regex to verify it has at least one capital letter and at least one number, then return either “Password created” if it does, or “Wrong format” if it doesn’t. I’m trying to use an AND statement inside of my conditional statement and I know it’s not optimal, I just don’t understand why it doesn’t work at all.

Here’s the code:

```
import re
password = input()

#check input for at least one cap letter and at least one number

if re.match(r"[A-Z]*", password) and re.match(r"[0-9]*", password):
    print("Password created")
else:
    print("Wrong format")
```

Edit: To everyone helping and asking for clarification, I’d like to apologize. The original code did not have the asterisks because I’m new to StackOverflow and did not use the correct formatting. I’m also new to asking coding questions so I’ll give some more context as requested. I’ve since changed the code to this:

```
import re
password = input()

#check input for at least one cap letter and at least one number
if re.search(r"[A-Z]*", password) and re.search(r"[0-9]*", password):
    print("Password created")
else:
    print("Wrong format")
```

Here are some example inputs and their expected vs actual outputs:

In: “Greatness” Expect: “Wrong format”
Actual: “Password created”
In: “12335” Expect: “Wrong format”
Actual: “Password created”
In: “Gm16gs” Expect: “Password created”
Actual: “Password created”

If I’m missing any more context please let me know as I am still new to this.

Update: I’m a moron. It wasn’t the and, it was the asterisks. Thank you so much everyone. I’ve marked the first answer as correct because the comments show me that I should’ve been using “+” and not “*”

Comment: What makes you say it "doesn't work at all"? You haven't shown any example of it failing.

Comment: @KellyBundy, you’re absolutely right, I apologize as I am still a bit new to asking good questions. When I use the code as shown, even with re.search as suggested by Mr Fooz and Unmitigated it returns “Password created” if there’s EITHER at least one number or at least one Capital letter. It’s only supposed to return “Password created” if the input contains at least one of both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) to find a match anywhere in the string. `re.match` will only return a match if the match starts from the beginning of the string.

```py
if re.search("[A-Z]", password) and re.search("[0-9]", password):
```

Comment: Their `match`s both match, though.

Comment: Thank you, that was a dumb dumb moment of mine, I will say that it still does not work with the and operator. Again, I know it should be more efficient, but I like experimenting and I can usually figure out what’s going on.

Comment: @Dharco Can you provide an input that this not work with?

Comment: @KellyBundy The original version of the question did not have the asterisks.

Comment: That's my point.

Comment: @Unmitigated any input containing a number or a capital letter returns “Password created”, when it should only return “Password created” if both are present. E.g. “1elco” returns “Password created” and so does “Greatness” and “e1ccd” and “12345”, etc.

Comment: @Dharco That's not true. It outputs "Wrong format": https://ideone.com/LwpoFU

Comment: @Dharco I cannot reproduce that for any of the strings you provided. They all output "Wrong format".

Comment: @Dharco The issue may be that you did not remove `*` from your regular expressions (as in my answer), since that matches **0** or more characters. So anything matches.

Comment: Looks like I was right that you should've pointed that out explicitly?